# how does wpf find ApplicationCommands in a commandbinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am confused as to how the commandbinding knows where applicationcommands is. It's not a property of the control containing the command binding, so does the xaml parser just look up the hierarchy till it finds it?

If that is the case, then if I place all my commands inside my app class, will they also be found automatically? Ultimately this is what I'm hoping for. I just want to know where to make my commands so that they can be accessible easily from xaml

```
  <UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Properties"
                    Executed="EditPreferencesExecuted"
                    CanExecute="CanAlwaysExecute"/>
   </UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's built-in. When you're designing your own commands, you have to include the namespace in your control's declaration tag, and then reference the namespace and the command using the namespace marker you picked.

Here's an example from a UserControl of mine which used the Helix 3D Toolkit libraries. In the control declaration, I included:

```
<dxr:DXRibbonWindow 
x:Class="Shell" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
[etc...]
xmlns:h="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf"
```

Using the commands implemented in that namespace then required just declaring them like this:

```
        <Button Content="Left View" 
         Command="{x:Static h:CameraController.LeftViewCommand}" />
```

The `h:CameraController` class in the library then defines a static ICommand property which processes the command:

```
    public static RoutedCommand LeftViewCommand = new RoutedCommand();
```

And in the constructor for that class is this code:

```
        this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(LeftViewCommand, this.LeftViewHandler));
```

...which supplies an instance-based binding for the XAML system to use. In your CommandBindings XAML snippet it would look something like this:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="h:CameraController.LeftViewCommand"
                    Executed="SomeExecuteMethodInCodeBehind"
                    CanExecute="SomeExecuteTestInCodeBehind"/>
   </UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

Thus, to answer your question in summary, you have to put the command in a namespace, reference the namespace in your XAML markup, and supply a binding, either in code or in a XAML declaration.